# Add multiple categories with the category badge on the publication widget

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Elementor offers a publishing widget to display articles. I use it to display personalized posts : referencing. These listings all have categories, for example "Bar", Hotel".

Elementor offers via the publishing widget a card style, which allows to display a badge. By default, this badge displays only one category.

[image: Elementor Pro Badge]

I read a lot of topics on the Internet, for example on this [GitHub](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/6480).

I tried to create plugins with this code inside

```
add_action( 'elementor/widget/posts/skins_init', function( $widget ) {
  
    class issue6480_skin extends \ElementorPro\Modules\Posts\Skins\Skin_Cards {
        protected function render_badge() {
            $taxonomy = $this->get_instance_value( 'badge_taxonomy' );
            if ( empty( $taxonomy ) ) {
                return;
            }
            $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
            if ( ! is_array( $terms ) ) {
                return;
            }
            ?><div class="elementor-post__badges"><?php
            foreach( $terms as $term ) : ?>
                <div class="elementor-post__badge"><?php echo $term->name; ?></div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }

        public function get_id() {
            return 'cards_multi_badge';
        }

        public function get_title() {
            return __( 'Cards Multi Badge', 'elementor-pro' );
        }
    }

    // register the skin to the posts widget
    $widget->add_skin( new issue6480_skin( $widget ) );
} );
```

But it is impossible to make multiple categories work and display them. Do you have any idea which files I should turn to in order to create this code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I merged your answer, this one on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementor/comments/wal7if/how_to_create_colorcoded_category_badges_on_cards/) as well as some work with ChatGPT and finally got it to work.

In the functions.php, paste this code - This will make all the categories show and I've added that they become clickable as well:

```html
/* MULTIPLE BADGES ON POST */
/* --- */
add_action( 'elementor/widget/posts/skins_init', function( $widget ) {

    class cards_multi_badge_skin extends \ElementorPro\Modules\Posts\Skins\Skin_Cards {
       protected function render_badge() {
    $taxonomy = $this->get_instance_value( 'badge_taxonomy' );
    if ( empty( $taxonomy ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy );
    if ( ! is_array( $terms ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ?><div class="elementor-post__badges"><?php
    foreach( $terms as $term ) :
        $category_link = get_term_link( $term );
        if ( is_wp_error( $category_link ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        ?>
        <div class="elementor-post__badge">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
        </div>
        <?php
    endforeach;
    ?></div><?php
}


        public function get_id() {
            return 'cards_multi_badge';
        }

        public function get_title() {
            return __( 'Cards Multi Badge', 'elementor-pro' );
        }
    }

    // register the skin to the posts widget
    $widget->add_skin( new cards_multi_badge_skin( $widget ) );
} );
```

This will create a Skin in the Post Widget called 'Cards Multi Badge'. Make sure that you choose that Skin so this will work as shown below:

[Choosing Card Multi Badge in the Skin option of the Post Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUce8.png)

After that, as you'll see the categories are a jumbling mess so I've added the following CSS to make it neater. It might not be on the image as you might have wanted but at least it works. For some reason, `position: absolute;` makes the positions of these wonky.

The CSS was added by:

1. Clicking on the Edit for the Post Widget
2. Click on the Advanced Tab
3. Scroll down to Custom CSS.

```css
.elementor-posts .elementor-post__badge{
    position: relative !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    background-color: #D8115A !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    font-size: 9px !important;
    line-height: 1 !important;
}

.elementor-post__badge a{
    color: #fff !important;
}

.elementor-posts .elementor-post__badge:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -6% !important;
}
```

That should make it work, as mine did on this [Blog Page.](https://alphacontent.eu/blog)

Hope it helps!